# pagination is not working properly for Twilio in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, twilio

I am trying to paginate the records for Twilio and after taking the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485160/pagination-is-not-working-in-twilio-call-logs-laravel)

I have added the next page and previous page url and its showing successfully but when I am opening the url, its showing the error i.e.

```
"code": 20003,
"detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.",
"message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided",
"more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003",
"status": 401
```

Here is my code :

```
public function listcallsapp(Request $request){
  $calls = $this->twilio->calls->page([], 50);

  $data = [];
  $i = 0;
  foreach($calls as $call){
      $data[$i]['sid'] = $call->sid;
      $data[$i]['from'] = $call->from;
      $data[$i]['to'] = $call->to;
      $data[$i]['direction'] = $call->direction;
      $data[$i]['status'] = $call->status;
      $data[$i]['duration'] = $call->duration;
      $i++;
  }
  
  return response()->json([
      'message'=>'Call Logs!',
      'code'=>200,
      'prev' => $calls->getPreviousPageUrl(), 
      'next' => $calls->getNextPageUrl(),
      'data'=>$data,
      'status'=>'success'
  ]);
}
```

Where I am missing, please help me out. Also, If any other way, please suggest.

Comment: `when I am opening the url` - you didn't show us the code that does that. Use `getPage()` to get the URL you get from `$calls->getPreviousPageUrl()` etc.  [Maybe this answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542942/twilio-how-to-do-pagination-with-messages/65200354#65200354).

Comment: I am working on postman, so there is no any view,